# Spquery Attachment from list display in webpart

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(DropDownListSelectCategory.SelectedItem.Value);

            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query =
                string.Format(
                    "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE'></FieldRef></OrderBy>");


            query.RowLimit = 10;
            query.IncludeAttachmentUrls = true;

            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

            Repeater1.DataSource = items;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
```

I am using this query to take all columns from a list and display in a Repeater, but i want it also to include a attachment because it dont include in , i want it to include a hyperlink attachment.

Answer (score 0):

see this function for getting attachments..

```
public void GetListAttachments(string site, string listName)
{
//StringBuilder sAttNames = new StringBuilder();
using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(site))
{
    using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList oList = oWeb.Lists[listName];

        SPListItemCollection oListItems = oList.Items;
        foreach (SPListItem item in oListItems)
        {
            SPAttachmentCollection collAttachments = item.Attachments;

            if (collAttachments.Count <= 0) return string.Empty;

            foreach (var attachment in collAttachments)
            {
                //your attachment here
                //sAttNames.Append(attachment.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
//return sAttNames.ToString();
}
```

Hope it helps...